# MYSQL SELECT Multiple Rows into one row

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, this is complicated for me to get out there, but here we go.

I have a family/person attendance table containing the following fields:

| mail_no (FamilyID)
| meid (Person ID)
| date
| status (A/P)|

On the family attendance screen, I need to pull the data and group it in the following format:

| meid | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 124 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

Currently, my PHP looks like this:

```
$year = "2020";
$where_clause = "AND ATDATA.mail_no='".$myrow['mail_no']."' AND ATDATA.status='A'";

SELECT meid,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-01' ".$where_clause.") as month1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-02' ".$where_clause.") as month2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-03' ".$where_clause.") as month3,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-04' ".$where_clause.") as month4,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-05' ".$where_clause.") as month5,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-06' ".$where_clause.") as month6,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-07' ".$where_clause.") as month7,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-08' ".$where_clause.") as month8,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-09' ".$where_clause.") as month9,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-10' ".$where_clause.") as month10,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-11' ".$where_clause.") as month11,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATDATA WHERE LEFT(ATDATA.date,7)= '".$year."-12' ".$where_clause.") as month12
  FROM ATDATA 
  WHERE ATDATA.mail_no='".$myrow['mail_no']."' AND ATDATA.status='A'
  GROUP BY meid,month1, month2, month3, month4"
```

I'm getting the following output, which has the meid's split per row, but the underlying data is grouped on mail_no. How can I get the data grouped by meid instead?

| meid | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1752 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 198 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 199 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 |

Comment: That said, consider handling issues of data display in your application code. After all, that's what it's there for :-(

Comment: The whole reason behind this endeavor is I'm using the ApPHP DataGrid plugin for my site, and it needs a single dataset to show the result. I COULD just use two php loops and two sql queries and be done with it, but then I have to recreate the wheel to output the data. Was trying to be a big boy and use the big boy tools :)

Comment: FWIW, I think you're trying to use the hammer for what the screwdriver was meant for.

Comment: I solved my issue by using PHP to build the sql statement and added a UNION for each sub member from the familyID. Thanks for forcing me to back up and look at the big picture.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and then accept that answer, if you like.

Answer (score -1):

hmmm hey

Just group by 'meid', remove the months in the group by... Then do counts where month = Jan... month = Feb... in your select...

Comment: I'd need explanation for changing that. I cannot 'see' how to pull data for a subset not knowing the subset